# XSD to apply different restriction to last item in a list?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

If have an XML format of the form:

```
<msg>
   <item id="0" valueType="xxx"/>
   <item id="1" valueType="xxx"/>
   <item id="2" valueType="xxx"/>
   ...
   <item id="n" valueType="yyy"/>
</msg>
```

The items are complex types with elements and attributes policed by a schema.
The `valueType` attribute can take one of a number of strings defined in an enumeration. However one of those `valueType` strings may **only** be used in the last item in the list.

Is there a clean way of adding such a restriction in the schema?

( I could create an `itemLast` type almost identical to `item` but with a different enumeration for `valueType` but that feels messy and adds additional complications to any XSLT file. )

Answer (score 0):

Your `itemLast` idea would be needed to treat the last item differently from the others in XSD 1.0, where dependent types are not supported.

If you can use XSD 1.1, you can add an assertion to the content model of `msg` to impose a special restriction on the last `item`:

```
<xs:assert test="item[last()]/@valueType = 'yyy'"/>
```

This assertion would be placed just before the closing `xs:complexType` tag for the `msg` type definition.

---

Here's an improvement to the above assertion to allow an empty list of `item` elements:

```
<xs:assert test="not(item) or item[last()]/@valueType = 'yyy'"/>
```

Thanks to @MichaelKay for noting the uncovered case.

Comment: Note, this also imposes a constraint that the msg must contain at least one item. A different assertion can be used if you also want to allow the msg to be empty.

Comment: Unfortunately the parsers xsd parsers I have to hand are all 1.0. Python does offer a library (xmlschema) that supports 1.1 so I could write my own simple validator.

Comment: One point, however, is that the restriction really applies to all 'items' except the last one. Can the test statement include a for loop?

Comment: @IanStroud: I find both of your comments confusing: (1) If XSD 1.1 is supported, you don't have to write code to validate this constraint; otherwise, you do.  (2) If XSD 1.1 is supported, you don't need a `for` loop because the asserted XPath covers the concern without iteration.

Comment: To clarify. The xml editors and tools we normally use do support xsd 1.1. To test any 1.1 feature I have downloaded a python schema library but I then need to create my own python validation script to actually use that library and verify the xml against the 1.1 schema.

Comment: item[last()]/@valueType only checks the last item in the list. Am I correct in saying that item/@valueType would check every item in the list? But how could I run the assert on every item except the last one?

Comment: @IanStroud: All `item/@valueType` attribute values would already be restricted to some enumerated type as described in your question using usual XSD 1.0 techniques.  It's only the last element's special condition that requires the special case covered by an assertion.